# White space appears on hiding column header in detailInit in kendo ui grid

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-grid

[image]

I have a hierarchical kendo grid in which I would just like to show only master column headers and hide the rest so all sub-grids correspond to a single main header.

I have used css: "**.k-grid tbody .k-grid .k-grid-header { display: none;}** " to hide the column headers but this shifts the column header row to the bottom of sub grid in the form of white space as can be seen in the above image, seems to be some kind of white footer.

Is there any other way to hide the sub column headers ?

Comment: Provide a working example, otherwise it's hard to help

Comment: Like @Dekel said, a working example would be helpful. Other than that, did you check for any kind of margins that might still be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the following style was successful in hiding that white space :

```
**.k-grid tbody .k-grid .k-grid-header { height: 0;border-bottom-width: 0; overflow: hidden; display: none;}**
```